# Complex Number Quotient Equality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In many standard books (John B. Conways's for example) the proof of the differentiation theorem of complex power series relies on the following equality
\begin{equation}
\frac{z^n-w^n}{z-w}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{(n-1)-k}w^{k}\text{, }
\end{equation}
which is easy to prove (by induction for example), noting that
\begin{equation}
z^n-w^n=(z-w)(z^{n-1})+(z^{n-1}w-w^n)=(z-w)(z^{n-1})+w(z^{n-1}-w^{n-1})\text{, }
\end{equation}
so, resembling the good old division algorithm for integers
\begin{equation}
\frac{z^n-w^n}{z-w}=z^{n-1}+w\frac{(z^{n-1}-w^{n-1})}{z-w}\text{, }
\end{equation}
and so on. But none of the books at my disposal seem to give a hint on why the equality holds, which make me think I'm missing something, and there is a much more easy way to prove the equality. Any thought's about this?

Comment: What kind of “why” are you looking for? – In my opinion that identity is “almost obvious” if written as $z^n-w^n = (z-w)(z^{n-1} + z^{n-2}w + \cdots + w^{n-1})$, or with the substitution $u=z/w$ as $u^n-1 = (u-1)(u^{n-1} + u^{n-2} + \cdots + 1)$.

Comment: Thank you, @MartinR, I think the substitution makes the trick for me, as the "substituted equality" can be easily derived from the geometric sum.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is usually done the other way around: The geometric sum formula is derived from that identity :)

Comment: @MartinR, Well, I usually derive the geometric sum formula from the fact that $S_n(z)=S_{n-1}(z)+z^n$ and $S_n(z)=1+zS_{n-1}(z)$, but there are a lot of proofs!